# Google Tag Manager - Android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have used following code to implement GTM

**to initialize GTM**

```
public void initializeGTM(Context context) {
        //GTM setup
        tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(context);

        // Modify the log level of the logger to print out not only
        // warning and error messages, but also verbose, debug, info messages.
        tagManager.setVerboseLoggingEnabled(true);
        PendingResult<ContainerHolder> pending = tagManager.loadContainerPreferNonDefault(GTM_CONTAINER_ID, R.raw.gtm_k4cqpb_v13);
        // The onResult method will be called as soon as one of the following happens:
        //     1. a saved container is loaded
        //     2. if there is no saved container, a network container is loaded
        //     3. the request times out. The example below uses a constant to manage the timeout period.
        pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
                ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
                containerHolder.getContainer();
                if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    /**
                     * TODO
                     * remove condition and logs after GTM testing
                     */
                    if (DEBUG)
                        Log.e(GTM_LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(R.string.gtm_container_load_error));
                    return;
                }
                ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
            }
        }, GTM_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        mAnalytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
        mAnalytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

        mTracker = mAnalytics.newTracker(TRACKER_ID); // Replace with actual tracker id

    }
```

**I have use mTracker to just record screen name**

```
 if (mTracker != null) {
        mTracker.setScreenName(fullName.toString());
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

    }
```

*and for rest of the datapush and dataevents I am using DataLayer object*

The major issue which I am struggling with is, in GA report when I filter with ***App Version secondary dimension***  then

- Under app version I can see trace with both versionName as well as versionCode
- Behavior -> screen names are properly recorded with versionName
- Behavior -> TopEvent -> Event is getting recorded with versionCode
- Conversation -> ecommorce -> Transaction is getting recorded with versionCode

*I have traced GA request by using Charles proxy and in GA I can see versionName as well as versionCode values under variable"av"*

Please assist as I getting nuts and now out of all the options I can think of.

Thanks